# Increase variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

I have a variable I only want to increment if the condition is met in the for loop. The other code in the if statement works perfectly but the variable never increments. Is it possible to do this in jQuery?

Here is a simplified example of what I have been trying:

```
var i = 0;
for (var c = 1; c < 3; c++) { 
    if(condition){
        i++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I apologize for my question being a little unclear.

Here's what I am actually trying to do:

```
<button id="showNew">Show Next Button</button>

<button id='button1' style="display:none;">Button 1</button>
<button id='button2' style="display:none;">Button 2</button>
<button id='button3' style="display:none;">Button 3</button>

<span id="value1" style="display:none;">123</span>
<span id="value2" style="display:none;">456</span>
<span id="value3" style="display:none;">0</span>

<script>
var i = 0;
for (var c = 1; c < 3; c++) { 
    var start = jQuery('#value' + c).text();

    if(start != "0"){
        jQuery('#button' + c).show();
        i++;
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#showNew').on("click", function () {
        jQuery('#button' + ++i).show();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The first two buttons show when the page loads but I have to click the "#showNew" button 3 times before the third button is shown.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mczwg7qw/) and it works fine so there must be a conflict with something else on my site. The weird thing is if I put "alert(i);" immediately after the for loop on my site I get the number I'm looking for (2). It appears to be reseting "i" back to zero once it reaches the onclick for some reason.

Comment: Which variable? That's the point of the `c++`. No need for jQuery here.

Comment: What's `condition`? It's not defined so the `i++` part will never execute.

Comment: What you have looks fine, assuming `condition` is ever true. Can you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: By the way, it's possible in *JavaScript*. JavaScript !== jQuery!

Comment: The code works fine > http://jsfiddle.net/s3yv6s1c/

Comment: @BenM: *Your* code works fine, but we don't know what `condition` is in *their* code. *Their* code *would* work fine if we assume `condition` is truthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem. Since "i" was correct before the onClick, I created a new variable with the value of "i".

```
var m = i;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#showNew').on("click", function () {
        jQuery('#button' + ++m).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I still don't understand why "i" was resetting once it reached the onClick though

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet works like you want. I just replaced the `condition` with `true`. It alerts 1, then 2.

```js
var i = 0;
for (var c = 1; c < 3; c++) { 
    if(true) {
        i++;
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can't reproduce the problem" and "your code works fine" are helpful contributions, but they should be comments, not answers.

Comment: I didn't say I can't reproduce the problem, or that his code works fine. I said that the code snippet that I posted in my answer works the way the asker wants his to work. So maybe they can compare the two and see what might be wrong with their code.